# All Cache Operation failed

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I am using ignite for caching in my system
when I am using single ignite node and restart my server or services it work fine but when I am using multiple ignite node and restarting the server or services it show all cache operation failed.

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation could happen, when you shut down more nodes than the number of [backups](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuring-backups) configured for caches. Such situation called "lost partitions".
It can be fixed by [control script](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#resetting-lost-partitions).

Regarding the situation below, is your cluster in-memory?

> when I am using single ignite node and restart my server or services it work fine